# Looking for a simple PM software running on our own intranet server and allows time tracking

Tags: pm-software

**I also asked the question at [software recommendations stack exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/which-simple-project-management-software-running-on-our-own-intranet-server-allo).
Please consider answering there since this seams to be the right place.**

I'm looking for a simple PM software that is installed on our own server and allows time tracking.

I only need:

- several projects
- several users (10-20)
- several tasks per project
- time tracking, i.e. how much time was spent on each task and how much time was estimated beforehand, and ability to add some comment on a task (e.g. why it did take longer)
- web interface would be an advantage (since we have Macs and Windows machines)
- Outlook integration would be an advantage, but is not necessary
- simple overview and maybe warnings if some task is not in budget
- a software that can be installed on our server

I don't need to upload files, email, GANTT charts, chat, wiki and the other stuff. The team is all on site and uses other tools for file exchange, mail etc.

It should be only really simple to enter the time one spent on a task since this is by far the most common task and done by most people.

The product hasn't to be free but should not be too expensive - a monthly fee or initial costs of more than 1000€ will definitely be a show-stopper.

I would be grateful if you could provide me some links since I have found no solution that allows all of that.

Comment: [Software requirements are always out of scope on PM:SE](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) see the section on what not to ask here.  Although there are some opinions below, they will be obsolete and misleading five minutes after any of the vendors issues a new release/patch.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Thanks for the advice. Where could I ask such a question then?

Comment: I don't know, except to say that SE is the wrong place to ask.  Many people try to ask for software recommendations/evaluations, but those questions are consistently out of scope.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a risk. I am wearing two hats, trying to help but with the risk of adding commercial information which does not help. A general link to an independent source to answer such a question would be a nice approach I think, but that's something for meta.

Comment: Hi Onur, you might check out [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), a new Stack Exchange Beta site. The site is all about software recommendations, but ***be sure to take a look around the site first as they have some pretty stringent requirements for what types of questions they take***. Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Hi @Onur, We are using http://www.orangescrum.com since last 1 year for project management. Its awesome. It allows us to track all type of tasks and also plan accordingly. It is also free for 1 month. And its cost is very less

Comment: Take a look at http://www.asitrack.com. It's pretty much what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my expirience Redmine works fine for small projects.

Most things you mentioned are quite simple to achieve and it's not overcomplicated in general. Modules you don't plan to use can be easily disabled.

It's free and has good plugin repository, so you can add lacking things like budget management.

Comment: This is the one we'll have a closer look at first.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for which I am biased is Invantive Vision (I work there); it allows time registration through web frontend and Outlook calendar on workflows and projects. It has customizable task flows and advanced features such as financial cash flow prognosis and complex invoicing.

Some competitors:

- [Timetell](http://www.timetell.nl)
- [Assistance Software add-on to Navision](http://www.assistancesoftware.com)
- [Software voor project management (Dutch only)](http://www.ikdoeprojecten.nl/page/software-voor)

You might also want to check out the wikipedia page on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software